# hive query can't generate result set via jdbc

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm new at Hive and Hadoop. In my tutorial, I want to create table as

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveCreateDb {
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Register driver and create driver instance

    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);

        // get connection

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/mydb", "root", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();


        stmt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + " employee ( e_id int, name String, "
                + " salary String)" + " STORED AS TEXTFILE");

        System.out.println("Operation done successfully.");

        con.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("class not found!!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("sql exception!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

When I run code I get this error

```
sql exception!!! java.sql.SQLException: The query did not generate a result set! at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:393)
at tr.com.vedat.hive.HiveCreateDb.main(HiveCreateDb.java:25)
```

So, I couldn't find solution. Can anyone help me to find bug and lead to me correct way?

Comment: I don't use Java, Hive, or Hadoop (so it isn't okay for me to answer), but from other experience and a Google search, I'd place a bet on you needing to use stmt.execute for a query that makes a new table instead of executeQuery. The executeQuery is probably for select queries (DML) while execute is probably for DDL. Look those up if you want to understand the difference.

Comment: @PaluMacil ,  executeQuery and execute can use create table or schema operations mostly. I used executeQuery for creation on RDBMS before and it worked. For Hive, I found several tutorials and all of them do creation with executeQuery. After your comment, I tried with execute and it works. Thanks a lot. I have been a victim of tutorials :)

Comment: In that case, I posted an answer and linked to a discussion where someone said it changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like the Hive driver changed over time to be more restrictive over time. See this [Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/EZe5z7HXJb4)

Use `stmt.execute()` for a query that makes a new table. of executeQuery. The `executeQuery()` is now only for select queries (DML) while execute is probably for DDL (data definition).

This makes sense because most drivers I've seen in other languages (Python and C# in my case) will separate the read only actions from the method that can actually change the data structure.

This [page shows the usage of executeQuery()](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.4/ds_Hive/hiveclient.html) for DDL:

```
 ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
```

The examples of `execute` here are Python, so you can note that all the DDL in the Java example uses `executeQuery`.

Comment: I know the difference usage of DML and DDL methods but in this case, I used DDL method as used in tutorials, so it lead me to the wrong way. Thanks a lot for your answer and research.