# Hive JDBC Connection returning "query did not generate a resultset"

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have built hive-jdbc from git and trying to execute a basic jdbc query to fetch a resultset. For some reason the query is throwing the following exception.

```
16/07/01 22:08:12 INFO Utils: Supplied authorities: localhost:10000 
16/07/01 22:08:12 INFO Utils: Resolved authority: localhost:10000 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: opening transport org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport@55360888 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslClientTransport: Sending mechanism name PLAIN and initial response of length 16 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: Writing message with status START and payload length 5 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: Writing message with status COMPLETE and payload length 16 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: Start message handled 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: Main negotiation loop complete 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: SASL Client receiving last message 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: Received message with status COMPLETE and payload length 0 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: writing data length: 71 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: reading data length: 109 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: writing data length: 183 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: reading data length: 109 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: writing data length: 100 
16/07/01 22:08:12 DEBUG TSaslTransport: CLIENT: reading data length: 53 
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: The query did not generate a result set!  
   at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:459)   
   at com.kris.mond.sample.HiveQuery.main(HiveQuery.java:20)
```

The following is the snippet of the code I am using,

```
     try { 
         Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
            System.err.println("Could not load the driver");
            System.exit(1);
        } 
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hduser", "*******");
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select account_id,account_parent,account_description from account");
```

As suggested in another post, I am using executeQuery for DML but still unable to fetch the resultset.

I would appreciate some help on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It'd be better if you printed and posted the entire stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Duffy, updated the post as per your suggestion

Comment: Is there more?  Not much of an improvement.

Comment: As far as exception stacktrace goes that is all its throwing, updated the log messages along with stacktrace

Comment: Sorry, can't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hive query can't generate result set via jdbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340332/hive-query-cant-generate-result-set-via-jdbc)

Comment: I did check that post and I am using executeQuery for DML as the post suggests for no avail. never mind thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get the resultset after the following patch in HiveStatement.java

```
public boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException {
    runAsyncOnServer(sql);
    TGetOperationStatusResp status = waitForOperationToComplete();

    **// The query should be completed by now
 -->   /*if (!status.isHasResultSet()) {
 -->     return false;
 -->   }*/**
    resultSet =  new HiveQueryResultSet.Builder(this).setClient(client).setSessionHandle(sessHandle)
        .setStmtHandle(stmtHandle).setMaxRows(maxRows).setFetchSize(fetchSize)
        .setScrollable(isScrollableResultset)
        .build();
    return true;
  }
```

For some reason **status.isHasResultSet()** is returning false even though a resultset is available.