# java.sql.SQLDataException: [Cloudera][JDBC](11300) A ResultSet was expected but not generated from query

Tags: java, hive, jdbctemplate

I am using following code to fetch records from a hive table.When i run the query in query console or through impala, it returns expected data. However, using code, it's giving error. Please assume that `validationQuery` variable has correct query string because i am getting result when running separately.

```java
       try (
                Connection conn = Objects.requireNonNull(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).getConnection();
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()
        ) {
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(validationQuery);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                log.info(rs.getString(1));
                log.info(rs.getString(2));
            }
        }
```

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: [Cloudera][JDBC](11300) A ResultSet was expected but not generated from query "....
    ". Query not executed. 
    at com.cloudera.impala.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SStatement.checkCondition(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeWithParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
```

Following is the query:

```sql
   with current as (
    select table_name,key_column_value, attribute_name from tableA
    where id= '6169646831575698485'
),
prev as (
select r.id,table_name,key_column_value, attribute_name,status,adj_request_status,value,original_value from TableA d
   inner join TableR r on r.id = d.id
   where date = '2023-06-15' and status in ('PASS') 
   and nvl(r.Datatype,'')='People'
   group by r.id,table_name,key_column_value, attribute_name,status,value,original_value
    )
select prev.id, prev.table_name , prev.key_column_value, prev.attribute_name,value,original_value from current 
inner join prev on current.key_column_value = prev.key_column_value
where current.table_name = prev.table_name
group by prev.id, prev.table_name , prev.key_column_value, prev.attribute_name,value,original_value
```

And so far, i've tried these methods to capture the output:

```java
       List<Map<String, Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(validationQuery);
```

```java
        jdbcTemplate.query(validationQuery, resultSet -> {
            String Id = resultSet.getString(1);
            String table_name = resultSet.getString(2);
            String key_column_value = resultSet.getString(3);
            log.info("The following values are fetched from database");
        });
```

But all are giving same error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hive query can't generate result set via jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340332/hive-query-cant-generate-result-set-via-jdbc)

Comment: Please add the query string to your question.